`ethers.getContractAt()` returns an overload error
I am trying to use the following function as shown below:
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const iWeth = await ethers.getContractAt(
        "IWeth",
        networkConfig[network.config!.chainId!].wethToken!,
        deployer
    )

But this gives me an error saying:
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(name: "IWeth", address: string | Addressable, signer?: Signer | undefined): Promise<IWeth>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Signer'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(name: "YourContract", address: string | Addressable, signer?: Signer | undefined): Promise<YourContract>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"IWeth"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"YourContract"'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(nameOrAbi: string | any[], address: string | Addressable, signer?: Signer | undefined): Promise<Contract>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Signer'.

Can anyone help me out on this?
